# Knockout Protected Observable and mapping plugin

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Protected observable requires parameters passed to the function e.g. :

```
var item = function(param)
{
  var me = this;
  me.itemProtected = ko.protectedObservable(param);

}
```

I don't know inner workings of the KO mapping plugin, but if I use it to map Json data to my model protected observable will not work. I assume it is mapping properties only as observables and ignoring protected observables altogether. The binding syntax:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, null, viewModel);
```

Is there a way to map json data and preserve protected observable?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ViewModel = function(data)
{
   this.itemProtected = ko.protectedObservable();
   return ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);

}
```

The JSON data offcourse need to have a member called itemProtected for this to work

edit: Disclamer, I do not know what a protectedObservable is and its not part of the core KO library.

edit:

- Solution1: http://jsfiddle.net/LFCWe/ Needs to commit for json data to take
- Solution2: http://jsfiddle.net/LFCWe/1/ This fiddle uses the create
  method and thus the value from JSON will be commited directly

Comment: No disrespect meant, but the question is about protected observable, so if you do not know waht it is I don't see why answering at all.

Comment: Instead of being a douch, add a link to which library u are using. My above code works with pausableObservables and other third party observables.

Comment: My apologies, I recognise you have good intention, here is the demo fiddle that Ryan Niemeyer posted:

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/X9rRa/

As you can see he is manually passing data via parameters to the function. That works for me when I use dummy data, however when I try to map data retrieved from the server, protected observable stops working.

Comment: Its ok, its soon 16:00 here and I've been working hard all day, easy pissed ;) Check my fiddle, my above solution seems to work?

Comment: I looked into pausableObservables and they do better job for my needs. However it is tedious job enumerating every single one on the object in order to pause and resume - I have a complex view model. Is there any way to pause and resume all properties on the object?

Comment: Not built in, you can extend it yourself pretty easy, for example let it take a object with an array, each pausableObservable adds it self to the object, then have a method on htat object that pauses all observables